# How to remove "array" in front of np.array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

i have created an list of list but the problem is that i have the word array in the list. how can i remove this word ?

```
listofEdges.append(value_edges)
```

1. LIST OF EDGES -< Minimum -> [array([4, 0]), array([5, 0])]
2. I want to get this result:
   LIST OF EDGES -< Minimum -> [[4, 0],[5, 0]]

thanks for the help.

Comment: You’ll need `value_edges.tolist()`, as you have a list of two numpy arrays. However, if you wish to maintain numpy functionality, these will need to remain as they are.  (numpy arrays and lists, are *very* different things).  [Docs reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)

Comment: sorry i meant np.array and not a list. Your suggestion helped me and solved the problem. Many Thanks